# Como atualizar página e não enviar dados duplicados para o banco em PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

Gostaria de saber se alguém tem exemplo ou pode me explicar na seguinte questão:

No caso do usuário atualizar a página, após o envio do primeiro formulário, não seja enviado novamente os dados para o MySQL.

Minha aplicação esta em PHP, já pesquisei, mas ainda não consegui solucionar.

A aplicação é formada por 5 formulários em uma única tabela, mas o preenchimento é uma a uma.

Answer (score 8):

Uma outra alternativa:

é você criar uma variavel de sessão para verificar se já houve uma requisão, veja:

```
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' )
        {
            $request = md5( implode( $_POST ) );

            if( isset( $_SESSION['last_request'] ) && $_SESSION['last_request']== $request )
            {
                echo 'refresh';
                // opa! é refresh!
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['last_request']  = $request;
                echo 'é post';
                //salva o que tem que ser salvo
            }
        }
    ?>
```

Fonte: http://wbruno.com.br/php/diferenciar-refresh-f5-de-postsubmit/

Comment: Pô cara, vlw demais, muitíssimo obrigado ao dois, só não votei, pois preciso de 15 pontos!

Answer (score 6):

Uma solução é fazer um redirecionamento logo depois de inserir as informações no banco. Mesmo se o usuário atualizar a página o POST enviado antes não vai ser reenviado pelo navegador.

Exemplo:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['....'])) {
 // salva no banco
 if($salvou_no_banco) {
   // redireciona para a mesma página (algo como um "refresh")
   header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); 
 } else {
   // algum erro! carrega a mesma página novamente
   // se o usuário atualizar aqui o máximo que vai acontecer é receber o erro novamente
 } 
}
```